# Angular scope variable is null when using ng-include (added a plunkr)

Tags: angularjs

The model in the $scope isn't there when I try to access it in the save function.
As per the code below: `desc` has the value from the text input, however `desc2` does not.

Is there anything wrong with the code, or am I missing something when it comes to the use of the $scope?

Html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myModel.description">
```

JavaScript

```
MyApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.save = function() {
        var desc = this.myModel.description; // This has a value
        var desc2 = $scope.myModel.description; // This does NOT have a value
    };
}]);
```

**EDIT:**
Added plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/3l9ZE7O2wpbfnH7XPA9X?p=preview

This problem seem to be related to using ng-include.
If I don't use ng-include then it seem to work fine.

Comment: are you using controllerAs syntax??

Comment: Added plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/3l9ZE7O2wpbfnH7XPA9X?p=preview
I see that the problem goes away if I don't use ng-include, but that doesn't seem like a solution as I like to have my controllers in their own templates

Comment: What do you mean by `service`? In AngularJS service is a kind of helper object and I don't see any here.

Comment: Turns out the service has nothing to do with it, I will rename the question title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-include` element introduces a child scope. Now your `myModel` is attached to a child, but your controller's `$scope` is the parent. Parent scopes can't see their children's variables, but children can see their parents'.

You can add `myModel = {};` to your controller and it should work fine. That way the child scope references his parents' `myModel` and doesn't create his own.